# Генерация ссылок

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

подскажите как сделать генератор ссылок.

Нужно что-бы при нажатии на кнопку сгенерировать 15 ссылок такого вида: https://site.com/62738383

Вместо 62738383 сгенерировать рандомные числа.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь стандартным модулем random.

Comment: Проблема в том что я только начал изучать Python, искал и на гитхабе что-то похожее, но толку 0.

Comment: `[f'https://site.com/{random.randint(0, 10000000)}' for _ in range(15)]`

Comment: Спасибо за код, но вообще не понимаю как дальше реализовать все 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
import random

def gen_links(count=15):
    while count:
        yield f'site.com/{random.randint(0, 10000000)}'
        count -= 1

for link in gen_links():
    print(link)
```

Comment: Благодарю, попытаюсь теперь соединить с телеграм ботом 